# Change SharePoint notifications account

Tags: 2013, email

When the users get a an email notification from SharePoint, they get that from an email account. Something like sharepoint@email.com.

I want to change the account the email notifications are sent from. I do NOT want to change the email of the administrative account, but the account itself. So it will be sent from newaccount@email.com

Anyone know the steps in order to achieve this?

Comment: You can configure the outgoing email name to anything you want. Just a heads-up.

Answer (score 3):

Navigate to Central Administration -> System Settings -> Email and text messages section -> Configure outgoing e-mail settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it via central admin:

- Directly go to this link http://CAurl.com/_admin/globalemailconfig.aspx
- Central Admin> System Settings> Configure outgoing e-mail settings[image]
- Or use the powershell

  $SMTPServer = 'mail.dotnetsharepoint.com'
  $FromAddress = 'jlakshmitulasi@dotnetsharepoint.com'
  $ReplytoAddress = 'jlakshmitulasi@dotnetsharepoint.com'
  $Charset = 65001

  $CAWebApplication = Get-SPWebApplication -IncludeCentralAdministration | Where { $_.IsAdministrationWebApplication }
  $CAWebApplication.UpdateMailSettings($SMTPServer, $FromAddress, $ReplytoAddress, $Charset)